# Body's adaptations to training in hot conditions?

Tags: training

Roger Federer, a professional tennis player, spends time in his off-season training in the dessert of Dubai, where temperatures can be extremely high.  What physiological adaptations does the body make in response to this training, and how do such adaptations enhance performance in cooler conditions?

Comment: I think this is off topic for this site, because you haven't said what the problem is that you're facing and what help you're looking for.. The FAQ says to ask "practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face". You'll get a better answer that way anyway.

Comment: Thanks Kate.  Maybe this is better suited to biology.stackexchange.  I'm happy if a moderator will transfer.

Comment: Actually, i dont think this is off-topic, at least not as much as it would be in biology SE. To please Kate the question could be rephrased to something like: "Ive found some routines that suggest training in high temperatures. How would it affect my workouts and my performance in typical conditions ?"

Comment: I agree with @kate that in the current form it's off topic. It's a broad, general question, unrelated to the poster.

Comment: Personally, I don't have a problem with this question - seems like an easy jump from Roger Federer to the OP wondering how these training conditions may help or hinder.

Comment: I voted to close only to have it migrated to [biology.SE], bad thing that in the beta you can't vote for that when closing.

Comment: I would suggest looking at this other [question about training in the heat](http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/6523/are-there-any-benefits-to-running-in-the-heat/6832#6832). If anything, I'd say it's a duplicate.